# WSL: Unable to view the folders (appear as file) in Windows explorer if using symlink, but works if symlink on the same directory

Tags: linux, windows, symlink, windows-subsystem-for-linux, explorer

No idea why but it seems that Windows explorer unable to view symlinked directories that the target is not on the same directory as the source target.

Is there a way to fix it? As it also make win32 applications unable to read the files under the symlinked directory. (I understand Windows equivalent `mklink` exist, but I need to do it in WSL's `ln`.)

Thanks a lot.

Sysinfo:

- Windows 10 Pro 2004 Build 19041.264
- (No idea how to check WSL build number)
- WSL2
- Subsystem uname: `Linux PC 4.19.104-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Wed Feb 19 06:37:35 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- Ubuntu: 
  `No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID: Ubuntu
  Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
  Release:        18.04
  Codename:       bionic`

Example:

```
$ pwd
/mnt/d/symlink_test/innerFolder
$ mkdir source
$ touch source/testfile
$ ls source
testfile
$ ln -s source target
$ ls -l
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 user user 4096 Jun  6 10:55 source
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user    6 Jun  6 10:55 target -> source
```

Now view the output in Windows explorer:

As you can tell, the `target` folder is recognizable by Windows Explorer

[image]
As well as the file `testfile` is accessable in Windows Explorer
[image]
Counter Example:

```
$ rm -rf target #Just clean things up
$ ls
source
$ ln -s /mnt/d/symlink_test/innerFolder/source ../upper_target #make a symlink to upper dir, or any directory that is not in the same dir, with the source dir being absolute path
$ ls -l .. #List files on the upper dir
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 user user 4096 Jun  6 11:03 innerFolder
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user    6 Jun  6 11:04 upper_target -> /mnt/d/symlink_test/innerFolder/source
$ ls ../upper_target
testfile
```

**However**, but now, if you view it in Windows Explorer, the `upper_target` will become a single file instead of a folder, like above:

[image]

Comment: For regular Windows filesystems, a symlink is an `IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK` (0xA000000C) reparse point. WSL will create this type on a drvfs volume for a relative target in the same filesystem. But for an absolute target path in the Linux namespace (e.g. "/mnt") it has to use an `IO_REPARSE_TAG_LX_SYMLINK` (0xA000001D) reparse point. This can only be evaluated within WSL. From Windows, trying to follow it fails with `ERROR_CANT_ACCESS_FILE` (1920). You can verify the reparse point type that's set on a file or directory via `fsutil reparsepoint query <filename>`.